# Нюансы применения регулярных выражений

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Есть два механизма реализации регулярок: ДКА и НКА.  Можно ли как то переключаться между ними?

Comment: А что такое ДКА и НКА?

Comment: Детерминированный/недетерминированный конечный автомат

Comment: можно, нужно просто реализацию выбирать:)

Comment: Я прочитал добрую половину книги которую вы посоветовали вчера) пока ничего о переключениях механизма. Пока что просто говорится о том, что в таких то инструментах нка а в таких то дка)

Comment: А, Вы решили, что есть некий флажок, который переключает реализацию? ну-ну:). 

И прочитать половину этой книги ещё ничем не поможет. Это же не бульварное чтиво.

Comment: Что бы ответить на этот вопрос, нужно сначала сформулировать что означает "Детерминированный/недетерминированный конечный автомат". При написании регулярок - никогда не сталкивался с этим. недетерминированный ~ неопределённый? Т.е. автомат дающий неопределённое поведение - это странно звучит. В вопрос нужно добавить больше конкретики, ссылки на определения, а лучше сами определения.

Comment: Посмотрите это видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_rkHzhXueo возможно много нового для себя откроете.

Comment: @nick_n_a вопрос вполне конкретный. и нка/дка - это особенности внутренней реализации движков.

Comment: @KoVadim Если движок умеет "переключатся" на одну из - то ответ - профайлить - засекать время обработки и тестить. Если движок использует один из - то логично ответить - тот на который заточен движок.

Comment: при чем здесь профайлер? Этого вопроса даже нет.

Comment: Давайте ещё раз сначала "Есть два способа реализации библиотеки REGEX А и Б".  И "можно ли переключатся между А и Б"? Если библиотеку написали методом А, то понятно что на метод Б её не переключить, верно? Есть конечно вероятность что в библиотеку заложили и А и Б одновременно, думаю это очень маловероятно.

Comment: так, а где же профайлер?:) 
а по поводу нка/дка ответ тут - http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/constants и он такой - на откуп конкретной реализации стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: В C++ есть 6 реализаций регулярок, по умолчанию - `ECMAScript`, НКА. Остальные - это обычные POSIX-варианты, `basic`, `extended`, `grep`, `egrep`, `awk`. Я [`тут на кое-что похожее ответил`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37963296/3832970).